# Can I use a .net domain for selling goods?

Tags: domains, legal, business

I have a .net domain. I plan to use it for selling goods/commercials. Is that ok? Are there any rules about domain usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2225/when-should-i-not-use-com-as-a-gerneric-top-level-domain-com-vs-net-org-e/2227#2227) to a different question (not near enough for me to mark this as a duplicate) covers it. In short, there are no rules, just conventions that mostly tend to be followed.