# Does domain extension affect seo?

Tags: seo, top-level-domains, google-ranking

Does domain extension affect SEO rank? For example, I know that the extension `.com` means commercial, or `.org` means something non-commercial but how about SEO ranking stand-point?

`.com` vs `.website` vs `.me` vs `.us` vs `.co`

Comment: Sorry but there already exists dozens of questions and answers on Pro Webmasters regarding SEO TLD's. You may also find the following questions helpful [When to use a top level domain](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2225/when-should-i-not-use-com-as-a-generic-top-level-domain-com-vs-net-org-e), [Does TLD or server location effect SEO](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/does-server-location-or-tld-affects-seo)

Answer (score 1):

I think for SEO it won’t matter which domain name extension you choose. We know that `.com`, `.net` are more popular than others but it will not help you in SEO.

SEO totally depends on your website content, keyword selection, strategies you use and some other aspects.

Your domain extension selection should be based on what audience you want to target. For Ex.: if you are from UK and you are planning to target UK audience then domain with extension `.co.uk` will be good. But finally all things depends on how you do SEO for your site.

Also I would like to indicate that you should choose domain extension as per your business profile, if you are organization then `.org` is good , if you are having commercial business then `.com` is good, etc.